# pass query params from cloudfront to api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I created a lambda function with a API gateway and Cloudfront distribution in the front

in the cloudfront behaviors I disabled caching

[image]

this is the lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('rawQueryString is: ' + event.rawQueryString),
    };
    return response;
};
```

calling the api gateway I see the querystring in the lambda response
https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api?name=john

`rawQueryString is: '?name=john'`

calling the cloudfront distribution i can't see the querystring in the lambda response
https://xxx.cloudfront.net/api?name=john

`rawQueryString is: ''`

I tried with "Origin Request Policy"

[image]

but now when i call https://xxx.cloudfront.net/api?name=john

I get

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details?

Comment: updated. hope it helps. not much info honestly. is there anything in particular you want to see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should setup [origin request policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html) for your cache behavior. You can try with AWS managed [Managed-AllViewer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html#attaching-managed-origin-request-policies) policy or **create new one** just to forward the query strings:

[image]

Comment: I chose one of te predefined ones Managed-AllViewer that's supposed to forward headers, cookies and qurystrings right? but after doing that I get the message: forbidden

Comment: hmmm I created one with querystring only and it did work. still dont understand why Managed-AllViewe doesn't work. it contains much more scope.

Comment: @handsome I'm not sure either. I checked what I had in my CF+API combo, and I was using the policy I provided in the answer. CF must be forwarding something to API that the API gateway does not like.

Comment: I also got `Forbidden` using Managed-AllViewer, I'd really like to know why

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949466/2817604) !

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949466/2817604)

You cannot send `Host` - so make an Origin Policy passing as much as you want - but do not pass `Host` ! That's what produces the Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/pass-query-params-from-cloudfront-to.html

We need to enable the cloudfront origin, this can also be done through CDK through addBehaviour or default ones.