# CloudFront gives 403 when origin request policy (Include all headers & querystring) is added?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am trying to set up a CF distribution with custom origin name that points to a custom domain setup in Route53 with latency based routing (to multiple regions). This is because Regional API doesn't including user IP info (XFF header) whereas CloudFront does.

In doing so, I found a really odd behavior with CF. When I configure **Cache key and origin requests**, CF always give undesired output. Below is what works as I just have managed policy `CachingDisabled` for **Cache policy**.

[image: No Cache]

But this has an issue as none of headers is passed to the application, so I conifgured **Origin request policy** and added `AllViewer` policy since I would need all custom headers/queryparams from client to be forwarded.

[image: No Cache + Forward user params]

This however breaks as I get an 403 error.

```
{
  "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I've also tried **Legacy cache settings** with headers set to `All`, but this option also gives 403. I am suspecting it is something to do with some headers appended by CloudFront that get rejected at API Gateway, but I can't configure out..

What gives?

Comment: Confirmed. AFAIK there is no way to have a behavior just "forward" the request, in its entirety, with all headers and no caching, through CloudFront to a service such as APIGateway, Lambda, etc. IMO this is a major failing. Hopefully someone can prove me wrong!???

Comment: If you are using CloudFormation you can achieve this with `Headers: ["*"]` as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291562/how-to-configure-cloudfront-using-cloudformation-to-set-the-headers-property-i/57328128#57328128 however, the AWS GUI does not seem to allow you to produce the same result.

Answer (score 14):

I just encountered this problem and after checking with AWS support, turns out that when you set to pass all headers to the origin the 'Host' header is also passed and then API gateway receives an invalid host name in header and return 403

Comment: Thank you! oh man I never would have guessed passing Host did this!

Comment: I think the solution here is to create a Custom policy that allows specific headers through (like origin), but not host.  You would also need to allow query parameters through if required.  Using a Custom Policy got me through this.

Comment: the problem with the Custom policy is that you can't forward the Authorization header...

Comment: I think that it's why, when you create a Distribution of type `AllViewer` (with API Gateway) option for Origin request policy says: `This policy is not compatible with API Gateway`

Comment: In my experience, this is not only connected to API Gateway. Even with webhook.site as origin (for debug purposes) I get 403 error from the CloudFront itself.

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this, my first instinct was to go look for the error in [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/). This ruled out a lot of possibilities and as the comments suggest, missing headers is most likely the cause.  In addition, I was using WAF so that could also cause the error.

I turned on API Gateway request logging and WAF cloudwatch logging and tried a few combinations.  The main issue seemed to not be with the `CachingDisabled` Cache Policy, but in using it with the `AllViewer` Origin Request Policy. Switching to having no Origin Request Policy at all yielded an error - but it was one of *my* errors.  Sure enough, I was able to confirm that my endpoint was getting reached, and the source of the error was a missing `X-Signature` header. However, by making a custom Origin Request Policy policy and adding that header manually, I was able to start getting `200 OK` from my endpoint.  All that with the WAF working properly too.  The interesting thing here is that when defining the custom policy I only needed to specify that one header - cloudfront seemed to be forwarding many other things by default like `X-Forwarded-For` and `Host`.

Reading the docs more closely, it seems that there's a lot of implicit header-passing that goes on behind the scenes when using these policies.  Headers in the cache key are sent to the origin automatically, and `AllViewer` is really vague.  I was unable to find a list of explicit headers in the policy itself, but I suspect that it's [these ones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html). It's behaving as if it's passing those headers and *nothing else* with `AllViewer`, possibly not even `Host` or `x-apigw-api-id`, two headers that APIG seems to need.  I wasn't able to empirically confirm what's getting passed, but that's my working theory anyway.

The TL;DR here is that 1) yes, you can use `CachingDisabled` policy with APIG and 2) you need to be very careful to check what's actually getting passed from cloudfront to APIG.  In my case it was headers but depending on your use case you might also run into issues with cookies, compression support, or the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `OriginRequestPolicy.ALL_VIEWER_EXCEPT_HOST_HEADER` would be the answer - it's in the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.OriginRequestPolicy.html#static-all_viewer_except_host_header

However it's not showing up in TypeScript for me - I get an error saying it doesn't exist. I was able to use the code from this issue comment to get it working: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13408#issuecomment-1462403083

tl;dr:

```
....
cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
originRequestPolicy : cloudfront.OriginRequestPolicy.fromOriginRequestPolicyId(stack, `AllViewerExceptHostHeader`, 'b689b0a8-53d0-40ab-baf2-68738e2966ac'),
...
```

Comment: I revisited this recently and it seems like it's updated, so now there in the type information in TypeScript. It's now possible to use `OriginRequestPolicy.ALL_VIEWER_EXCEPT_HOST_HEADER`

Answer (score 1):

Spend some hours to figure it out.

In my case, Origin request policy `AllViewerExceptHostHeader` is the answer. But, it disabled when using custom domain in API Gateway. If my stack is going to use Router53 -> CloudFront -> Api Gateway, then simply delete custom domain.

[CloudFront Behavior Cache Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVdS9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue and just got it to work.

My use case was to setup a user friendly domain name and ssl certificate in front of a lambda function URL. When I set the Cloudfront cache policy to CachingDisabled and the origin request policy to AllViewer, my distribution would always return an HTTP 403.

I then updated the origin request policy to a custom policy where I explicitly listed the header I needed, then set it to include all query string and cookies as well.

This seems to have worked. Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following options defined in behavior worked for me with AWS CDK.

```
cachePolicy: cloudfront.CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
originRequestPolicy: cloudfront.OriginRequestPolicy.ALL_VIEWER_EXCEPT_HOST_HEADER,
responseHeadersPolicy: cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS,
```

Cheers!